# Merge 2 multidimensional dataframes on row and column index while skipping missmatches

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have to multidimensional dataframes of different sizes

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

default_entries = ['VOD','APPL','MSFT','PGO']
join_entries    = ['VOD','MSFT','PGO']

df_join = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],index=join_entries, columns=join_entries)
df_default = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((4,4)),index=default_entries, columns=default_entries)
```

Which gives me this

```
     VOD   MSFT   PGO
VOD   1     2      3
MSFT  4     5      6
PGO   7     8      9
```

and

```
     VOD   APPL   MSFT   PGO
VOD   0      0     0      0
APPL  0      0     0      0
MSFT  0      0     0      0
PGO   0      0     0      0
```

I now want to merge the two frames into a new frame that looks like this

```
     VOD    APPL   MSFT   PGO
VOD   1       0      2     3
APPL  0       0      0     0
MSFT  4       0      5     6
PGO   7       0      8     9
```

I basically want my default df to fill values that are missing in the join df, the reason for this is to rescale my data frame while preserving the order of elements.

I tried

```
pd.merge(default_entries, join_entries, on = default_entries.index, how='outer')
```

but it doesn't seem to like the dimensions. If anyone knows of a more elegant solution than building a loop that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
df_default.add(df_join)

output:
      APPL  MSFT  PGO  VOD
APPL   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN
MSFT   NaN   5.0  6.0  4.0
PGO    NaN   8.0  9.0  7.0
VOD    NaN   2.0  3.0  1.0
```

To deal with the order:

```
new_df = df_default.add(df_join, fill_value = 0)
new_df = new_df[df_default.columns.tolist()]
new_df = new_df.reindex(index=df_default.columns.tolist())
print new_df
      VOD  APPL  MSFT  PGO
VOD   1.0   0.0   2.0  3.0
APPL  0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0
MSFT  4.0   0.0   5.0  6.0
PGO   7.0   0.0   8.0  9.0
```

Courtesy of @Ted Petrou, use fill_value = 0 in the .add statement to fill NaN values with 0.

Comment: That would work if I can preserve the order of elements, i.e VOD,APPL,NSFT,PGO

Comment: This is quite good. You can replace the missing values in the add method with an argument. I think it's fill_value = 0.

Comment: Not sure if you can ensure that the columns are not changed when using add, but you can use reordered_df = unordered_df[df_default.columns.tolist()] after you add the two together

Comment: with unordered_df = df_default.add(df_join)

Comment: @marcus.london just switch the order. `df_join + df_default`

Comment: O, and new_df = new_df.reindex(index=df_default.columns.tolist()) to deal with the index order

Comment: @TedPetrou, gives the same result either way for me.

Comment: @senderle yup, you're right, I edited my answer to reflect the suggestion